# SageMaker XGBoost hyperparameter tuning versus XGBoost python package

Tags: xgboost, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

I am trying to do hyperparameter tuning of xgboost model. I started with AWS Sagemaker Hyperparameter Tuning, with the following parameter range:

```
xgb.set_hyperparameters(eval_metric='auc',
                        objective='binary:logistic',
                        early_stopping_rounds=500,
                        rate_drop=0.1,
                        colsample_bytree=0.8,
                        subsample=0.75,
                        min_child_weight=0)

hyperparameter_ranges = {'eta': ContinuousParameter(0.01, 0.3),
                         'lambda': ContinuousParameter(0.1, 2),
                         'alpha': ContinuousParameter(0.5, 2),
                         'max_depth': IntegerParameter(5, 10),
                         'num_round': IntegerParameter(500, 2000)}

objective_metric_name = 'validation:auc'

tuner = HyperparameterTuner(xgb,
                            objective_metric_name,
                            hyperparameter_ranges,
                            max_jobs=10,  
                            max_parallel_jobs=3,
                            tags=[{'Key': 'Application', 'Value': 'cxxx'}])
```

And get a best model with the following set of hyperparameters:

```
{
  "alpha": "1.4009334471163981",
  "eta": "0.05726016655019904",
  "lambda": "1.2070623852474922",
  "max_depth": "7",
  "num_round": "1052"
}
```

Out of curiosity, I hooked up these hyperparameters into xgboost python package, as such:

```
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(max_depth = 7,
                          silent = False,
                          random_state = 42,
                          n_estimators = 1052,
                          learning_rate = 0.05726016655019904,
                          objective = 'binary:logistic',
                          verbosity = 1,
                          reg_alpha = 1.4009334471163981,
                          reg_lambda = 1.2070623852474922,
                          rate_drop=0.1,
                          colsample_bytree=0.8,
                          subsample=0.75,
                          min_child_weight=0
                        )
```

I retrained the model and realized the results I got from the latter is better than that from SageMaker.
xgboost (auc of validation set): 0.766
SageMaker best model (auc of validation set):0.751

I wonder why SageMaker perform so poorly? If SageMaker usually perform worse than xgboost python package, how do people usually do xgboost hyperparameter tuning? Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Are you using same training set and testing set for both SM xgboost and python xgboost?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same training and testing set for both xgboost.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you are using a different version of XGBoost. Which image are you using? The script mode enabled open source XGBoost uses 0.90.